# Is there an appendix of documented sound changes?

Tags: resource-request, sound-change

I believe at one point I've seen online some sort of appendix where you can look up a particular phoneme, for example, and see how it either develops in certain languages, triggers some form of sound change in languages, or what it evolves into.

This is a very cool resource, but for the life of me I can't find it again. Does anybody know anything similar to this? (It doesn't have to be exactly the same website, just anything that has a similar function).

Comment: One rather ramshackle compendium of sound changes is [Index Diachronica](https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/).

Comment: Perhaps UniDia (http://www.diadm.ddl.cnrs.fr/index.php) but it's not highly functional.

Comment: You might look up the Stanford Universals Project.  There was a study there of palatalization that I found very useful.

Comment: Wikipedia has some lists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Sound_changes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Vowel_shifts

Comment: @Miztli Index Diachronica is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Great! I'll add that as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the particular source that the OP was after was [Index Diachronica](https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/), a large collection of various sound changes, originally collated to serve as inspiration for those wanting to create their own constructed languages.