# Is there a compendium for sound laws?

Tags: phonetics, datasets

Sound laws such as the Canaanite shift, which is the proposed law that Proto-NW-Semitic *ā -> Proto-Canaanite ō, and the celebrated Grimm's Law.

Is there a database that lists all transformations of ā -> ō in various languages?
Conversely, is there a database that can list ā -> [phoneme] sorted by which phoneme it morphed into?

Comment: See also these two questions https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/34733/9781 and https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/37727/9781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is [Index Diachronica](https://chridd.nfshost.com/diachronica/) that is available as a searchable online database (in the link given above) or as a pdf file with all the sound laws nicely typeset.

Comment: it's worth noting that index diachronica is far from complete even for the languages it does describe, many of its subgroupings are controversial, there is little to no distinction between universally-accepted and relatively tentatively suggested changes, and notation is not always completely consistent (but such is the way with random projects done for free online)